# Spring - best way to secure get request

Tags: spring

I wrote a web server with a spring boot, which returns json, depending on the query. I wonder how can I protect my server to json reimbursed only for specific addresses or applications. So that a regular user of the browser could not get the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way:

Use extra parameter like ?api_key=39802830831bed188884e193d8465226 and compare if the provided value matches one of the allowed values in database.

For security concerns you should use https.